# how to set on click listener to the path of svg?

Tags: android, xml, svg, vector-graphics

I have been working on drawing hall scheme and from server side I've got svg which contains several paths with id. My problem is detecting clicked svg path and retrieving id to draw hall scheme.

Comment: Android has no built-in ability to render SVGs downloaded at runtime. You would need to find some way to draw an SVG that also allows you to hook up per-path click listeners. You might use a `WebView` with suitable JavaScript libraries for the listeners. Otherwise, see if any [SVG libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/96?sort=created) offer your desired feature.

Comment: What is the environment? Android? Web app?